# Call C++ library in C#

Tags: c#, c++, function

I have a lot of libraries written in C++. I want to call these libraries from C#, however, I have met many problems. I want to know if there is a book or guideline to tell me how to do that.

Comment: http://geeklit.blogspot.com/2006/08/calling-c-lib-from-c.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569603/using-c-class-dll-in-c-application

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. DllImport - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(VS.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739%28VS.71%29.aspx)
2. Wrapper class - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/67cc9eea-a4fe-48bd-b8d5-f3c8051ba896

Answer (score 5):

If you google "c++ c# interop", you'll find tons of information on this topic.

A couple of links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301501.aspx
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235281(VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235281%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I recently had to wrap some c++ code in .NET. Although the c++ code was packaged as a dll, the interface was too unfriendly for P/Invoke, so I decided to write it in managed c++, or C++/CLI as it is apparently known now.

I found [this tutorial](http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/index.htm) very useful on the syntax. It's not so easy on the eye, but the content seemed pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of the book [C++/CLI in Action](http://www.manning.com/sivakumar/) which has a couple of useful sample chapters online, at that address.

This [intro on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/quickcppcli.aspx) is a good starting point.

The author of C++/CLI in Action has a number of articles on CodeProject, scroll down to the C++/CLI section on [his index](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=20248).

The [Wikipedia article on P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) has a number of reasons why you might not want to use that approach, with which I agree:

- loss of typing support by the compiler
- possible data type or alignment issues as you have to map types by hand
- need to pin garbage-collected objects

The best starting point on MSDN is the [summary article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx).