# Communicating between C++ and C#?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, c++-cli

I want to use both C++ and C# in my application.

C# for GUI design and C++ for processing.

But I don't have any knowledge about this. How to communicate between them.

I don't know where I have to begin and research.

Someone can tell me the overview about this technology? And if someone have document about this topic, please give it to me.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 for development.

Many thanks,

T&TGroup

Comment: Here is an example on how to use c++ library with c#. http://www.functionx.com/csharp2/libraries/cppcli.htm

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574801/call-c-library-in-c-sharp

Comment: They are very useful, I will read them. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

The technology you are looking for is [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), a proprietary language extension for C++, that allows interaction with .Net code.

The basic idea is this: You write your C++ libraries as ever in portable ISO C++. Then you add a thin wrapper in C++/CLI for those C++ components you want to call from C# (or any other .Net language for that matter).
Just be aware that C++/CLI is only intended to write code for interaction with .Net. Don't be tempted to write the implementation in CLI as well, as you will end up with code that is not portable and probably a lot harder to maintain than the pure C++ version.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on  what the architecture of your application should be, you can for example create two different application one that is the core and another that is the GUI and communicate through messaging.

On Windows you can use Windows [message queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for example, to let the two end point communicate with each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use C++ CLI or native C++. C++ CLI is managed code and native c++ will be unmanaged by the CLR. The choice between the two depends on your usage. There are certain limitations with C++ CLI.

Answer (score 1):

It depends totally on the architecture and requirement as well. You can write processing instructions in C++ (lib) use them in GUI. Can be done in VS 2010 as well easily