# how to use c++ class in c# project

Tags: c++, insert

I have a virtual studio c# window form project. I have use a c++ class to create its object

c++ class named PushSourceDesktop.cpp

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't make it a *virtual* project.  Whatever that means.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using C++ Class DLL in C# Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569603/using-c-class-dll-in-c-application)

Answer (score 0):

Swig provides a c# interface to c++, so that is one way.

See
http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/CSharp.html#CSharp.

There might be simpler ways if the amount of code you want call is small however...

All the best,

Tom