# How to compile a c++ program for use in a .net application?

Tags: c++, .net, dll, clr

I'm trying to compile a program written in C++ (SuitSparse, does sparse matrix calculations).  I need to compile it to be used by a csharp.net application.  What's the best way to do this?

1) Compile it and reference it like any other c++ dll?
2) is there any program that can convert this to clr (or something .net would understand better)
3) ??

Comment: might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using C++ Class DLL in C# Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569603/using-c-class-dll-in-c-sharp-application)

Comment: .net supports c++. (at least the tooltip for the .net tag on SO mentions it).

Comment: well, my questions is more about what's he best way to use the source code...i don't necessarily have to create a c++ dll

Comment: I wouldn't make a C++ DLL, I would statically link the C++ code into your C++/CLI project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use C++ DLLs in C# programs, but you can use C++/CLI DLLs in C# programs. [Create a C++/CLI wrapper for the C++ project and build it into a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569603/using-c-class-dll-in-c-sharp-application).

The alternative is to use COM interfaces, as Ed S. pointed out, but I think that doesn't provide a very C#-ish library feel. It really depends on what you feel most comfortable with, I would assume C# dlls.

Comment: what about P/Invoke? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Incorrect. You can reference native DLL's directly from a C# project if it exposes COM interfaces.

Comment: is creating the c++ dll and wrapper using the source the only way to use it from .net? (hopefully this is not too dumb of a question)

Comment: @EdS. COM seems like it's not the most natural way to interact with a library, I feel like a DLL would be much more natural for a C# developer.

Comment: @ColinD yes, what about P/Invoke?

Comment: @user1167650 you can either create a C++ DLL or statically link the C++ code into your C++/CLI wrapper. I prefer statically linking, rather than making a C++ DLL, because if you make a C++ DLL it's much harder to export classes and it's going to cause all sorts of headaches for you.

Comment: @Lirik: I was simply responding to your assertion that "You can't use C++ DLLs in C# programs,", which is incorrect.  Also, COM types can be used as if they were C# types, so it's not too bad really.