# ASP .Net Web Api adding 3th party dll library (ipropsapi.dll)

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, .net, dll

I need to integrate CCTV Camera controls to the Web API. The Panasonic provides two means of control (activeX and DLL). The Panasonic ActiveX plugin and MS Windows Server 2008 R2 does not like each other, so this leaves me with the DLL.
DLL are C++ libraries.

Panasonic PS-API: 
http://security.panasonic.com/pss/security/library/developer.html#SDK

I am looking for guidance, how to integrate the controls.

[Using C++ Class DLL in C# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569603/using-c-class-dll-in-c-sharp-application) thread describes inclusion of the .NET Class, where in my case is COM Class I think. The thread also mentioning a wrapper for functions within the dll.

I am looking for some super simple example of the dll referencing, inclusion, dll wrapping and usage.

Thank You all.

Comment: Hope this is what you are looking for : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh, the link was very helpful. it did helped me to understand it better, unfortunately the DLL or ActiveX plugin must be installed on Windows Server 2008 R2. and that is problematic. I tried to run the installation on two different 2008 servers. I ended up with scraping the original idea and I wrote little C++ console application with in-build DLLs which control the camera based on passed params.