# Integrate a C++ library on C# Graphical Application

Tags: c#, c++

I'm using a C++ library (openCV) and I wanted to make a graphical application and I'm used to program in C# so I could make a WindowsForms or WPF application. I dont want to use a similar C# library like EmguCV, I want a c++ library.

**Is there any way to make code in C++ and integrate it with a WindowsForms or WPF application?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using C++ Class DLL in C# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569603/using-c-class-dll-in-c-sharp-application)

Comment: In the specific case of OpenCV, there are a bunch of .net wrappers for it already, including ones available through nuget. I'd just use one of those if I were you.